# How to create a Header for a doctor's prescription

Tags: header-footer, letterhead

I'm a doctor and I was hoping to do my electronic scripts using XeLateX. I've been looking on how to do headers for letters. Below is a picture of how my current header layout is for written scripts, and I'd like to reproduce that. I've figured out how to do the top part of the header, but the contact details and address area underneath seems beyond me. They need to be in two columns, the left being the address, and the right (being right aligned) needs to be my contact details. Then I also need an area below the header line for the patient name, date, and the Rx symbol.

Below is the working sample for the top header I have so far. I'd really appreciate it if someone can show me the ropes on how to make this template. Thank you!!!

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{{\huge{\textbf{\textit{Dr Coenraad J van Schoor}}}} \\  MBBCh \\ PR no.: 0000000000\\HPCSA registration no.: MP000000 \\ {\Vlarge{General Practitioner}}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}%

\begin{letter}

This is a sample



\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the `KOMAscript` family, specifically the [`scrletter2`](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#p=153) document class. It is very powerful and customizable and likely contains all the features that you need.

Comment: Oh, and the download ([here](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en)) helpfully contains two dozen sample letters to help you visualize and build your template.